# How to check if request if cross domain or not in Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring, cross-domain

I need to check in spring application if request came from the page with the same origin or not, how to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `HttpServletRequest` to your handler method parameters and compare the user host and port with your server's host and port:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public void crossOriginTest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String userHost = request.getRemoteHost();
    int userPort = request.getRemotePort();

    int serverPort = request.getServerPort();
    String serverName = request.getServerName();

    // compare them
    // Maybe get the X-Forwarded-For
}
```

And if your server is behind a Load Balancer or something, take a peek at `X-Forwarded-For` attribute in order to identify the IP address of a client.

Answer (score 3):

Although Ali's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095180/1910582) has covered what you are looking for, to me it seems  you seek to control the cross domain request(s).

If that is the case I recommend you to have a look at Spring (*available from version 4.2*) support to control cross domain request via [@CrossOrigin](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html) annotation and xml configuration viz `<mvc:cors> <mvc:mapping path="/**" /> </mvc:cors>`.

For implementation details consult the Spring blogs [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) and [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)